# Como puedo saber si existe un archivo txt desde PLSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, archivo, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo en siguiente problema, estoy creando un Trigger en Oracle para que escriba información en un archivo txt, hasta aquí todo bien, puedo escribir sin dramas, el problema es cuando necesito añadir información al archivo, a parte de la que ya tiene. Entiendo que debo leer el archivo, extraer lo que contiene y juntarlo con el nuevo texto, el gran problema se presenta cuando intento abrir el archivo pero no existe. Como puedo agregar esta validación?(si no existe, que lo cree)

Este es el Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BAJOSTOCK
AFTER 
UPDATE
ON PRODUCTO
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
V_ARCHIVO UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
V_LINEA VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
IF :NEW.CANTIDAD <= :OLD.STOCK_CRITICO THEN

 --Aqui me da el errror, cuando no existe

    --Abro el archivo
    V_ARCHIVO := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('DIR_TMP', 'stock.txt', 'r');

  --Leo lo que contiene  
  LOOP
    UTL_FILE.GET_LINE (V_ARCHIVO, V_LINEA);
  END LOOP; 
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(V_ARCHIVO);--Lo cierro

  --Vuelvo a abrirlo y escribo
    V_ARCHIVO := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('DIR_TMP', 'stock.txt', 'w');
  --Escribo lo que tenía y el nuevo contenido
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_ARCHIVO,V_LINEA);
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (V_ARCHIVO, 'El producto '|| :OLD.DESCRIPCION ||' se encuentra en stock crítico, por favor revíselo');
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(V_ARCHIVO); --Cierro el archivo
END IF;

--Cierro el archivo si hay errores
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(V_ARCHIVO);
END;
/
```

Agradezco su ayuda....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesariamente hay que leerlo todo para agregar información.
Pero vamos por partes:

Considerando que en mi ambiente el query:

```
select  * from ALL_DIRECTORIES
```

Devuelve

```
OWNER   DIRECTORY_NAME  DIRECTORY_PATH
SYS     XMLDIR          /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/rdbms/xml
SYS     DATA_PUMP_DIR   /u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/
```

Por otra parte en mi directorio **/u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/** tengo el archivo: **dp.log**

Luego entonces para revisar si el archivo existe se puede usar la funcion FGETATTR. Según mi ambiente puedo poner:

```
DECLARE
  nombreDirectorio CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100):= 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
  nombreArchivo    CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'dp.log';
  existeElArchivo  BOOLEAN;
  longitudEnBytes  NUMBER;
  numeroDeBloques  NUMBER;


BEGIN

    UTL_FILE.FGETATTR( nombreDirectorio, nombreArchivo
                     , existeElArchivo, longitudEnBytes, numeroDeBloques);

     IF existeElArchivo THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'El archivo '|| nombreArchivo  ||' existe ' );
     ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'El archivo '|| nombreArchivo  ||' NO existe ' );
     END IF;

END;
/
```

Lo cual me arroja como salida que el archivo existe.

2. Para agregar al archivo no hace falta leerlo todo. Puedes abrirlo en modo de agregado.

En lugar de indicar que es para escritura (por el parámetro final **w**):

```
V_ARCHIVO := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('DIR_TMP', 'stock.txt', 'w');
```

Puedes usar el parametro **'a'**:

```
V_ARCHIVO := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('DIR_TMP', 'stock.txt', 'a');
```

Es importante comentar que si abres el archivo en modo '**a**', si no existe el archivo Oracle lo creará en ese momento y lo abrirá en modo '**w**'

Comment: gracias crack!! el modo **'a'** solucionó mi problema, pero nunca está demás aprender algo nuevo (FGETATTR). Muchas gracias bro te pasaste @Alvaro

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

oracle-apex oracle-plsql

Pienso que no es una práctica recomendable hacer esto dado que el acceso al sistema operativo compromete en varios aspectos al trigger:

- Imprevisibilidad
- Bloqueo indeterminado
- Demora de inicio/fin de la llamada al S.O.
- Manejo de errores
- Aspectos de seguridad

Entre otros

Considero que un mejor abordaje sería el consumo de una API que ofrezca el servicio y pueda ser mejor controlada.